# Firebase cloud messaging notif wont stack together

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Ive been trying to build app that uses firebase cloud messaging i notice then when there is already a notif then i send another notif it replace the other one.

I want to make the notification stays there so the user can read all the notif, i tried unique tag to each notif i send but still doesnt work.

```
final data = {
  'click_action': 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
  'status': 'done',
  'message': title,
  'body' : body,
};

try{
  http.Response response = await http.post(Uri.parse('https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send'), headers: <String, String>{
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'key=MY_CODE'
  },
      body: jsonEncode(<String, dynamic>{
        'notification': <String, dynamic> {'title': title, 'body': body ,'android_channel_id':'dbfood',"tag" : createTag(3)},
        'priority': 'high',
        'data': data,
        'to': token
      })
  );

  if(response.statusCode != 200){
    print("Error");
  }
}catch(e){

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show
make the id as a random number

```
 await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
   1 + Random().nextInt(1000 - 1),
  //if static Id =>notification will be delete last notification received
  "${event.notification!.title}",
  "${event.notification!.body}",
  platformChannelSpecifics,
);
```